# Windows Mobile Device Center stopped working after windows 10 update

Tags: .net, operating-system

I have been using Windows Mobile Device Center in Windows 10 for about three months and haven't had any problems but when I updated my Windows this week, Windows Mobile Device Center stopped working and would not recognize my device.

Did anyone see this situation?

I tried different compatibility settings (Vista, sp2 , sp3 ) run as administrator etc, but nothing worked. Does anybody know of a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the command prompt as administrator and type the following two commands:

```
  REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RapiMgr /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

  REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WcesComm /v SvcHostSplitDisable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Restart your PC and see if that works. Hope that helps. If that doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling the application after making changes to the registry editor. That's what worked for us!

It was an update to windows that also caused this issue for me. As Microsoft do not support windows mobile device center anymore, that's probably why.

Comment: many many thanks , I wrote this situation msdn forms and send some tickets , ı could not  get an answer

Comment: Yeah, I was lucky to have found a solution somewhere online. Took a while but we got there in the end!

Answer (score 2):

If Windows 10 is showing you the "This app isn't working correctly" notification when you try to start Windows Mobile Device center, first reinstall it as it suggests.  use the 6.1 installation available from the Microsoft Download Center:

- 32-bit
- 64-bit

This should make the message go away, but WMDC still does not launch, either nothing happens or it will be stuck on the splash screen.

1. Now go to the Services applet, and look for the "Windows Mobile 2003-based device connectivity" service.
2. Double-click it to view it's properties, choose the "Log On" tab and select "Local System account" as the log on mode.
3. Tick "Allow service to interact with desktop"
4. restart the service.
5. look for the "Windows Mobile-based device connectivity" service.
6. Repeat the step 2,3 and 4.

You should now be able to start the service and WMDC will work as expected again.